# -bash: curl: команда не найдена

Tags: unix, vim, vimrc

Здравствуйте. Недавно я решил перейти с IDE на Vim. Занялся его настройкой и решил установить плагины. Как плагин менеджер я выбрал Vim-plug, но вот загвоздка, когда я ввожу команду для установки Vim-plug, выдается ошибка, мол команда не найдена(см. заголовок). Ниже - команда которую я ввожу в консоль Unix.

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

P.s. Я сижу на Windows 10, использую Cygwin.

Comment: Установите curl.

Comment: Нет повести печалнее на свете, чем повесть о десятке и цыгвинке.
Проверте `:set shell`. Метку замените: `unix` -> `cygwin`. "команда которую я ввожу в консоль Unix" - вы на удалённой машине запускаете команду?